# Does Eclipse support somthing like "Quick Outline" command, but for all projects?

Tags: eclipse

In Eclipse, the "quick outline" command lets you quickly jump to a method in the current class. Is there similar functionality that lets you quickly jump to ANY method in all projects?

Answer (score 2):

No,

There is CTRL+SHIFT+T and CTRL+SHIFT+R (Open Type and Open Resource) which will open any type / file in your workspace, and from here you can jump to a method. However, Eclipse does not keep an index of all methods in your workspace.

You can also do a "Java Search" -- which is a search with more context. For example, you can search your entire workspace for a method called setFoo.  This might help, but I wouldn't say this is a "Quick Way".